# Passing array value between two different click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I pass values ​​from an array from one event click to another with jQuery?

Here is an example of I want to do: the first click event adds or remove values from the array if the input checkbox is selected or not. In the second click I want to loop trough all the elements of this array.

```
var array=[];
 $( "input" ).on( "click", function() {
  var $input=$(this)
  if($input.is(":checked")){
  array.push($(this).val()); //append check box value to array if is selected
  }
else{
   array.pop($(this).val()); // remove check box value to array if is not selected
  }

 })
$('#cmd').click(function() {
     for (i of array) {
        console.log(array[i]); // loop trough all elements in array
    ...
});
```

Comment: Your code looks good, is it not working?

Comment: You sure the syntax `for (i of array)` is valid?

Comment: Yes, it valid. My problem is when a use the array outiside the first, it becomes empty

Comment: *outside the first click event scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok except two things. First for `for (i of array)`. Using `of` will return actual value as `i`, but you are using value as index in `array[i]`.

If you want use index then use `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` instead.

You can also use `Array.prototype.forEach()` but you can't break out of it's loop https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Second thing is that `.pop()` doesn't support parameter. Use code below instead of `.pop()`

```
var index = array.indexOf($input.val());
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

If your event handlers are in different scope and `#cmd` handler can't see the `array`. You might use this little bit bad solution for sharing the array between scopes :)

```
$("input").on( "click", function() {
  var array = $("#cmd").data("arr") || [];

  var $input= $(this);
  var value = $input.val();
  if($input.is(":checked")){
    array.push(value); /
  } else {
    var index = array.indexOf(value);
    if (index > -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  $("#cmd").data("arr", array);
});

$('#cmd').click(function() {
     var array = $(this).data("arr") || [];
     for (let value of array) {
        console.log(value); // loop trough all elements in array
     }
});
```

Comment: the for Loop it's ok, i have problems with the arrays values. Outside the scope of my first click event, the array becomes empty.

Comment: @mauriciosantos yes it's because you can't use  `.pop()` like that.

Comment: the pop with parameters works god. For example if I do the console.log(array) inside the first click scope it works nice. The problem is when I call the array outside the scope of the first click event, the array becomes empty.

Comment: @mauriciosantos no it doesn't work ok, because `array.pop()` will always removes last item from array. So every time input is unchecked last element from `array` is removed. Also define what you mean by "outside" and "empty"?  Are you sure your "outside" has access to your `array` variable? Does "empty" mean empty array or undefined value?

Comment: Sorry @Wanton "outside" mean out of the first click event( the event here i append the values to the array); and "empty" means the array without any values when i try to use it outside the first click event. I think the problem is related with the local and global declaration of the array variable

Comment: @mauriciosantos if those two event handlers are in different scope that array needs to be globally available somehow I'll edit my answer.

Comment: its working fine now, thanks for all your help  and sorry for my mistakes. I am new in programming...

Comment: @mauriciosantos we all been there :) If you think my answer is enough you shoud accept it as answer to your question,